# Matrix Multiplication Function with For Loop

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am having a terrible time trying to do this seemingly easy function. I can't figure out why this won't work.

My code:

```
C = matrix(0 , dim(matrixA)[1] , dim(matrixB)[2] , TRUE ) 
mat_mult = function(matrixA, matrixB){
for ( ii in 1:dim(matrixA)[1] ) {
   for ( jj in 1:dim(matrixB)[2] ) {
      for (kk in 1:dim(matrixA)[2] ) {
         C[ii,jj] = C[ii,jj] + matrixA[ii,kk]*matrixB[kk,jj]
      }
   }
 }


}
```

I'm just trying to multiply two matrices together. Any ideas?

Comment: You may need to wrap in braces `(1:dim(matrixA))[1]`

Comment: Or maybe use `nrow(.)` for `dim(.)[1]` and `ncol(.)` for `dim(.)[2]`. It's easier and more readable.

Comment: See help("%*%").

Answer (score 1):

You didn't declare the matrix c :

```
mat_mult = function(matrixA, matrixB){
c = matrix(0 , dim(matrixA)[1] , dim(matrixB)[2] , TRUE ) #This line
for ( ii in 1:dim(matrixA)[1] ) {
  for ( jj in 1:dim(matrixB)[2] ) {
    for (kk in 1:dim(matrixA)[2] ) {
      c[ii,jj] = c[ii,jj] + matrixA[ii,kk]*matrixB[kk,jj]
    }
  }
}
return (c)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes:

1. You should not call anything "c" in R, as "c" is the name of very important function.
2. You forgot to initialize the matrix "c"
3. You did not return the matrix "c"

Also, you better fix horrible indentation and inconsistent spacing, and instead of dim(x)[1] and dim(x)[2] better use nrow(x) and ncol(x)